# Add Input com Jquery e como pegar os dados desse input

Tags: jquery, get, input, value, create

Tenho 1 botão em JS que cria input. Só que eu não consigo pegar esses dados do input.
Consigo criar **cada input** com um **name diferente**, mas não faço ideia de ***como posso pegar esses valores pelo php***.
Tentei enviar a **var add** para fazer um loop, mas ela não consegue pegar o valor final.

Aqui fica o **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nLcvq9ej/)** funcionando o botão e o name diferente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, a forma mais correta de se fazer pelo PHP seria utilizando determinando o valor do input como um `Array`.

Ou seja. Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
var add = 1;
function add_fields() {
    var d = document.getElementById("content");
    add++;
    d.innerHTML += "<br /><label class='tooltips'>A ser excluído "+add+": <input type='text' name='solicitacao"+add+"'/></label>";
}
```

Você deveria fazer isso:

```
var add = 1;
function add_fields() {
    var d = document.getElementById("content");
    add++;
    d.innerHTML += "<br /><label class='tooltips'>A ser excluído "+add+": <input type='text' name='solicitacao[]'/></label>";
}
```

Simplificando: substituímos o `"solicitacao" + add` por `"solicitacao[]"`.

Ao fazer isso, o PHP acessará o valor de `solicitacao[]` através de `$_POST['solicitacao']`, e isso retornará um `Array` com todos os dados inseridos.

Dessa forma, tal operação se torna mais dinâmica, dispensando o uso de contadores para fazê-lo.

Lembrando que deve-se declarar esses inputs dentro do formulário (`<form>`), para poder enviar a submissão dos valores.

Comment: Boa, vlw. O código está certinho. Isso foi só um recorte.